# Adding a DLL file as reference in C#.NET project

Tags: windows, visual-c++, defragmentation

I am currently working on a project to perform disk defragmentation in Microsoft Windows environment. For that I want to use the in-built functions of the Windows defragmentation utility. I read somewhere that Windows uses "dfrgres.dll" file to perform defragmentation. So, I want to add "dfrgres.dll" file as a reference in my project. But I am not able to do so. This is the error message which I am getting when I try to add the specified DLL into my project:
"A reference to '...\dfrgres.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"


Please tell me where the problem is...or is there any other way to do it...??? Are there any other open source resources available over the internet for defragmentation...???

Regards,
Mr. Elusive

Comment: This DLL doesn't export any APIs.  You can't use it.

Comment: You could write something to use it, and then reference that, but you are goiing to be at the mercy of Redmond in terms of windows versions, service packs, patches....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated DLL or COM server to perform defrag, the low-level interface uses IOCTL codes to talk to the device driver.  Briefly [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There's a Microsoft employee [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx) that proposes a C# interface.  No idea if it still works on later versions of Windows.